# Hive: Create function if not exists

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

At the start of my hive script i have the statement:

`create function x as y using jar z;`

Now, if the function already exists, it will give me an error:

`Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionTask. AlreadyExistsException(message:Function x already exists)`

If i use `create function if not exists x as y using jar z;`, i will get this error:

`Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 7:192 cannot recognize input near 'if' 'not' 'exists' in function identifier`

The statement `create function if not exists` would work in Impala, but it seems that hive does not support it. Is that a way to do something similar in Hive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use following statements in hive to create temporary functions.

```
ADD JAR hdfs:///tmp/udfs/jar1.jar;
DROP  FUNCTION IF EXISTS rowid;
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION rowid AS 'com.example.hive.jartest.RowIdUDF';
```

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that my hql always runs even when the function already exists I opted for:

```
set hive.exec.drop.ignorenonexistent = true;

drop function concat_i_t;

CREATE FUNCTION x
AS 'y'
USING JAR 'hdfs:///z';
```

However, i would like to learn about a more elegant solution